# Post a comment on Github Pull Request via Command Line

Tags: github, command-line-interface, pull-request

Is there a way I can post a comment on a Github Pull Request via the command line? The ideas is that I want Jenkins to post comments on Pull Requests with a summary of the results of a script.

Comment: You can try jenkins plugin https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/GitHub+pull+request+builder+plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible without third party extensions.

You may be intrested in this: https://github.com/stephencelis/ghi

Sorry I can't help more!

Comment: Thank you ghi is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 4):

This is absolutely possible with nothing more than curl.

```
curl \
  -X POST \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer $GITHUB_TOKEN" \
  https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/hello-world/issues/42/comments \
  -d '{"body":"Hello Github!"}'
```

Read more about the API in use here https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/issues#create-an-issue-comment

**NOTE:** This assumes you have a Personal Access Token stored in an environment variable named `GITHUB_TOKEN`

Answer (score 3):

This is a little late, but this sounds like exactly what you are looking for:

```bash
gh pr comment 6 --body "Hi from GitHub CLI"
```

https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_pr_comment

Simply allows you to add comments to a pr from a given pr number.